# Grunt clean - use one sub-task under other sub-task

Tags: gruntjs

I have 4 sub-tasks under **grunt-clean**

```js
clean: {
    options: {force: true},
    lib: ['demo/client/lib'],
    jsTeamplate: ['src/js/*.template.js'],
    scripts:['dist/js'],
    scss:['src/css/*','dist/css']
},
```

I want to use sub-task lib under other 2 sub-tasks - **scss and scripts**.

How it should work: Whenever `clean:scss` is called then firstly it should clean its files and then it should run `clean:lib`.

The same workflow goes with `clean:scripts`

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize [grunt.registerTask()](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.registertask) to achieve this.

An excerpt from the documentation reads:

> If a task list is specified, the new task will be an alias for one or more other tasks. Whenever this "alias task" is run, every specified task in taskList will be run, in the order specified. The taskList argument must be an array of tasks.

Given your requirements, register a couple of additional Tasks in your `Gruntfile.js` as follows:

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
// ...

grunt.registerTask('foo', [ 'clean:scss', 'clean:lib' ]);

grunt.registerTask('quux ', [ 'clean:scripts', 'clean:lib' ]);

// ...
```

**Running the Tasks**

Then run the following commands via your CLI instead of `$ grunt clean:scss`:

`$ grunt foo`

*...The command above will run the `clean:scss` target, then the `clean:lib` target*

`$ grunt quux`

*...The command above will run the `clean:scripts` target, then the `clean:lib` target*